# Three.js - rotating texture on sphere geometry

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js, 3d

Is it possible to rotate loaded texture on sphere geometry in Three.js? I don't want to rotate the object, just texture that is applied to material. Let's say I have a sphere that looks like that:
[image]

And I just want it to rotate in x/y/z direction by n degrees to look like that:
[image]

Comment: No, this is not possible. Try it yourself [with `texture.offset(u, v)`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.offset) and you'll see that sphere geometries experience pinching on the poles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can do this. Even If you wanted to offset the texture, it wouldn't work, especially in a loop.

You should simply rotate the sphere:

```js
function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
}

render();
```

Comment: The thing is that when I tilt the object it is always facing center of its orbit (while orbiting) and by rotating texture I wanted to avoid that. Anyway, thanks for answer. Now I know that is impossible to rotate texture itself, so I have to look for some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired visual result, I would go with set of rotation order of a mesh, leaving UV settings of a texture as is.

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.set(1, 2, 7);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.prepend(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(2));

const orbitRadius = 5;
let orbitPath = new THREE.Path().absarc(0, 0, orbitRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
let orbit = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(orbitPath.getSpacedPoints(72)).rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5), 
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"})
);
scene.add(orbit);

let globe = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 16, 8), 
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "magenta", wireframe: true})
);
globe.rotation.order = "ZYX"; // set rotation order
globe.rotation.z = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(23); // inclination
globe.add(
  new THREE.Line(
    new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([new THREE.Vector2(0, -3), new THREE.Vector2(0, 3)]), 
    new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "aqua"})
  )
)
scene.add(globe);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  
  globe.rotation.y = t;
  globe.position.x = Math.cos(t * 0.25) * orbitRadius;
  globe.position.z = -Math.sin(t * 0.25) * orbitRadius;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```